# Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard::login() must implement interface Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject

Tags: laravel, jwt

I'm getting this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard::login() must implement interface Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject
```

whenever I want to login with my User.

However, I searched everything and all I found was implementing it to the User model, but already have that done as you can see here:

```php
namespace App;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Token creation:

```php
$user = User::where('steamid', $info->steamID64)->first();

if (!is_null($user)) {
  $token = auth()->login($user);
  return response()->json([
    'status' => 'success'
  ], 200)->header('Authorization', $token);
}
```

Why is this error still appearing eventhough I already changed everything the like the doc said?

Comment: try to clear config, `php artisan config:clear` also check for path of class in providers in config/auth.php

Comment: clearing the config and cache helped: ```php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear```

Answer (score 11):

You have to do just a simple step

Change user model line from this

> class User extends Authenticatable

to this

> class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject

and your problem solve.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code like this:

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

$user = User::where('steamid', $info->steamID64)->first();

if (!is_null($user)) {
    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success'
    ], 200)->header('Authorization', $token);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).